# How to register a user whose email contains a capital letter in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase email and password authentication for user authentication in my app. One user's email contains uppercase letters, but when I add the user on the Firebase console, it creates a user with the email converted to lowercase. For example, adding a user with an email of `AAAA@gmail.com` will create a user with an email of `aaaa@gmail.com`. Is it possible to add a user with the email in uppercase (e.g. `AAAA@gmail.com`)?

Comment: E-Mail are case sensitive (at least in case of Firebase Auth). So `AAA@gmail.com` and `aaa@gmail/com` will be considered as same the email. Is there any reason you are trying to store the email in original case ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to use the email as it is, including capital letters, when I use the original email in the app to connect to other services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I add the user on the Firebase console, it creates a user with the email converted to lowercase

That's what the Firebase console does. It will always convert the capital letters in the email address into lowercase letters. Why? Because the email addresses are case-insensitive. What does it mean? It means that while authenticating, the uppercase and lowercase letters are interpreted as being the same. That being said, all letters are converted to lowercase letters.

> Is it possible to add a user with the email in uppercase (e.g. AAAA@gmail.com)?

No, it's not possible to change that in the Firebase console. If you want to have the email addresses case insensitive, then you should store them either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) that way. But remember, while authenticating, the email address that is used is always lowercase.

Comment: I think you mixed up case-sensitive and case-insensitive.